# how to get an updated field in python-mysql after the field updated

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I used the following command to increase a field in mysql table in python.

```
 cursor,db_connection=await database_connection()
 await cursor.execute("update topics set last_voice_id=last_voice_id+1 where topic_id='%s'" % topic_id)
 await db_connection.commit()
```

i want to get the field `last_voice_id` after it's updated. how do i do this?

Comment: Your only option, I believe , is to select the record again by looking it up with topic_id (assuming it to be the primary key)